# How do I implement proper threading mechanism in rust to handle 2 async call at once from one main funciton

Tags: postgresql, rust, actix-web

All I am pretty new to Rust and I am still learning. Please pardon me if I say something wrong.

I am creating a very simple web application using Rust, The frameworks I am using are `actix_web`, and `postgres`, My use case is pretty simple. There is a PostgreSQL DB running on my local WSL; I just want to execute a simple `SELECT` query, my query is as follows: `SELECT * FROM payment`, the table is created in my DB and it does have values (meaning its not NULL). I want to display the output of the `SELECT` query on my web browser, for which I am using a struct to structure my data and `actix_web` package to build myself a web API.
I want to implement a simple functionality that when I hit the `'/'` on the local host it should show me my structured output from Postgresql on the Web.

There are functions I have written to handle all these operations. but I am getting an error on my runtime

```
thread 'actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:0' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.',
```

From this, I understand that my main function's thread is getting blocked for another async call while it was already serving one async call (Kind of a deadlock scenario I presume).

I tried to browse the web and found some stuff but still couldn't seem to find an exact understanding of how to mitigate this.

here is the code that I have written:

// datamodel.rs (model for Actix web)

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use crate::database::data_model::Payment;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize,Serialize)]

pub struct ApiHealthStatus {
    pub status: String,
    pub status_code: String,
    pub data: Vec<Payment>
}
```

// rest_api.rs

```
use crate::{web_api::datamodel::ApiHealthStatus, database::{self, data_model::Payment}};
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, error::BlockingError};
use futures::Future;
use postgres::Error;
use std::io;


async fn status_checker() -> impl Responder {
let res = web::block(|| database::db_connector::db_connect()).await;

match res {
    Ok(data) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(ApiHealthStatus {
        status: "OK".to_string(),
        status_code: "200".to_string(),
        data: data.await.unwrap(),
    }),
    Err(e) => {
        // Handle the error here
        // e is of type actix_web::error::BlockingError<postgres::Error>
        HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!("An error occurred: {:?}", e))
    }
  }
}


#[actix_web::main]
pub async fn actix_web_main() -> io::Result<()> {
println!("Starting web server at https://127.0.0.1:8080");
HttpServer::new(|| {
    App::new()
    .route("/", web::get().to(status_checker))
})
   .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
   .run()
   .await
}
```

//data_model.rs (model for DB)

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Payment {
    pub customer_id: String,
    pub amount: String,
    pub account_name: String,
}
```

// db_connector.rs

```
use postgres::{Client, Error, NoTls};
use crate::database::data_model::Payment;
use std::thread;

async fn db_client() -> Result<Client, Error>{
    let client = Client::connect("postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/backbone", 
    NoTls)?;
    return Ok(client);
}

pub async fn db_connect() -> Result<Vec<Payment> , postgres::Error> {
let mut client = db_client().await.unwrap();
    // let query = client.batch_execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment(customer_id 
    VARCHAR, amount VARCHAR, account_name VARCHAR)")?;
    let _query = client.query("SELECT * FROM payment", &[])?;
    // println!("{:?}", query);
    let mut all_transactions: Vec<Payment> = Vec::new(); 
    for row in _query{
        let pay = Payment{
        account_name: row.get(0),
        customer_id: row.get(1),
        amount: row.get(2), 
    };
    all_transactions.push(pay);
   } 
    Ok(all_transactions)
}
```

// main.rs

```
use actix_web::web;
use tokio::task;
mod database;
mod web_api;

fn main() {
    let api_service = web_api::rest_api::actix_web_main();
    match api_service {
    Ok(()) => println!("Exiting.."),
    Err(e) => {
        println!("{}", e);
    }
  } 
}
```

This is how my project is structured:

```
src
|- database
      | - data_model.rs
      | - mod.rs
      | - db_connector.rs
| - web_api
      | - datamodel.rs
      | - mod.rs
      | - rest_api.rs
| - main.rs
| - mod.rs
```

Comment: Not sure about this, but looking to your code you should not need `web::block()`, as you should be able to call `database::db_connector::db_connect()` directly and await the result.

Comment: Okay... I can try doing that